# QT - QDir count() returns zero

Tags: qt, function, count, return, zero

I´m new in using QT and I´m having troubles with a QDir count() function.

I have this code

```
obrazky = new QDir;
obrazky->setPath("obr");
pocet = obrazky->count();

...

textT.append(QString("%1").arg(pocet));
informativeText = new QLabel;
informativeText->setText(textT);
```

where "obrazky" is declared as QDir *obrazky; I have an "obr" folder in my project folder but the "pocet" variable is still 0. In "obr" folder I have a few image files.

Do you know what I´m doing bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that you're actually *in* your project directory when running this code. A simple call to `obrazky->absolutePath()` should help here, it will give you the full path name from your relative `obr` path segment.

Or, you could equally well use `exists()` to check that the directory exists (the *actual* directory, not the one you *think* it is). Since `count()` is equivalent to `entryList()->count()` and `entryList()` simply returns an empty list if the directory does not exist, that could well be the problem.

Comment: Thank you... I was in buildProject directory so I skipped out and back into the right dir. But what will happen if I´ll release the project to executable form. Will it be ok to change it back to obrazky->setPath("obr") if I suppose such dir exactly where the .exe will be?

Comment: @Peter, there are many ways to 'fix' this. You can insist the user run the program in the right directory, you can allow configuration of a directory, you can intelligently locate the directory from `$HOME` (for example) and so on.